# Pattern substitution in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Looking for some alternative to clean a tabular file containing informations between parenthesis.
It will be the first step to include in a pipeline and I need to remove every value inside parenthesis (parenthesis included).

What I have

```
> Otu00467  Bacteria(100);Gracilibacteria(99);unclassified(99);unclassified(99);unclassified(99);unclassified(99);
> Otu00469  Bacteria(100);Proteobacteria(96);unclassified(96);unclassified(96);unclassified(96);unclassified(96);
> Otu00470  Bacteria(100);Proteobacteria(100);Alphaproteobacteria(100);Rhodospirillales(100);Rhodospirillaceae(100);Azospirillum(54);
```

What I desire:

```
 Otu00467   Bacteria;Gracilibacteria;unclassified;unclassified;unclassified;unclassified;
 Otu00469   Bacteria;Proteobacteria;unclassified;unclassified;unclassified;unclassified;
 Otu00470   Bacteria;Proteobacteria;Alphaproteobacteria;Rhodospirillales;Rhodospirillaceae;Azospirillum;
```

My first approach was to split the second column by ";" , "("  , ")" and further join everything. Not bad but too ugly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
new_string = re.sub(r'\(.*?\)', '', your_string)
```

Comment: In your particular case should make no difference, as there are no nested parentheses, but of course this will also work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.sub`:

```
import re

with open open('file.txt') as file:
    text = re.sub(r'\(.*?\)', '', file.read(), flags=re.M)
```

This removes all occurrences of the text enclosed in parentheses. The `re.M` flag is the **multiline specifier**, which is useful when your string has newlines within the matching pattern.

Comment: Thank you. Edited.

Comment: The `m` flag only changes the behaviour of the `^` and `$` anchors, so it has absolutely no effect on this regex.

Comment: OTOH, it is always prudent to use `r''` syntax when specifying regular expressions to avoid unexpected problems with backslashes.

Comment: @Rawing Good point. I was getting mixed up with `re.S`, aka `re.DOTALL` :oops:

Answer (score 1):

I would try regexp for it. Something like that:

```
pattern = re.compile('(\w+)\(\d+\);')
';'.join(re.findall(pattern, string))
```

For each string

Answer (score 1):

This regex gets rid of parenthesized groups of digits, it also gets rid of any `'>'` characters, since it appears that you want to eliminate them as well.

```
import re

data = '''\
> Otu00467  Bacteria(100);Gracilibacteria(99);unclassified(99);>unclassified(99);unclassified(99);unclassified(99);
> Otu00469  Bacteria(100);Proteobacteria(96);unclassified(96);unclassified(96);unclassified(96);unclassified(96);
> Otu00470  Bacteria(100);Proteobacteria(100);Alphaproteobacteria(100);Rhodospirillales(100);Rhodospirillaceae(100);Azospirillum(54);
'''

data = re.sub(r'>|\(\d+\)', '', data)
print(data)
```

**output**

```
 Otu00467  Bacteria;Gracilibacteria;unclassified;unclassified;unclassified;unclassified;
 Otu00469  Bacteria;Proteobacteria;unclassified;unclassified;unclassified;unclassified;
 Otu00470  Bacteria;Proteobacteria;Alphaproteobacteria;Rhodospirillales;Rhodospirillaceae;Azospirillum;
```

This code works on Python 2 & 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Use re module to use regex
import re

#Open file and read data in data variable
data = open('file.txt').read()

#Apply search and replace on data variable
data = re.sub('\(\d+\)', '', data)

#Print data to output.txt file
with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.write(data)
```